# Documentation rep not shown in app achievements

Tags: bug, documentation, android-app, ios-app

Under "Last 7 Days" in the website image, you can see +2 Razor. This is an approved edit on some documentation. However this rep is not shown in the iOS app.

*I can only apologise for the lack of hand draw circles.*

**Website**
[image: Website]

**iOS**
[image: iOS]

Comment: We don't have any integration with the mobile apps right now, but I agree that we should do something for the rep event types even if a more meaningful integration isn't on the roadmap in the near future. There is, however, no excuse for the lack of the freehand circles.