# Reputation earned on Documentation is not reported in the mobile application

Tags: bug, documentation, android-app

I'm not sure if it's a bug/work in progress or that it's related to the fact that the documentation is still in beta, but the Reputation menu (in the Android App) doesn't show points earned by the Documentation.

Did some search on the topic but couldn't find anything related.

Comment: @Stijn thanks! Do you know it is going to be fixed in the future?

Comment: I've no idea, but in another duplicate [a developer said this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334426/documentation-rep-not-shown-in-app-achievements#comment395024_334426): *"We don't have any integration with the mobile apps right now, but I agree that we should do something for the rep event types even if a more meaningful integration isn't on the roadmap in the near future."*

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)